# python list comprehension: list of dicts to dict of lists with key intersection

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list with a variable number of dictionaries, for ex:

```py
var = [ {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 20, 'a': 10, 'c': 30}, {'c': 300, 'a': 100} ]
```

I need to extract the keys that are common to all dicts, make a list of their associated values, create a new dict out of it, and store it in the same variable:

The expected result would be:

```py
var = { 'a': [1, 10, 100] }
```

I can find the intersection of the keys with:

```bash
[k for k in var[0] if all(k in d for d in var[1:])]
```

But how can you do the rest of the transformation?

Comment: Are you specifically trying to do it in a single line of code with no intermediate variables/steps?  Because it's possible to do it that way, but it's easier and more efficient to do it in steps.

Comment: @Samwise Thank you for the comment; it would be great to know how to do it with a single list comprehension expression; I'm currently writing a workaround code with intermediate variables/steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you know the keys you care about, just iterate and pull them as you go:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_var = defaultdict(list)
for d in var:
    for k in common_keys:
        new_var[k].append(d[k])

new_var = dict(new_var)  # Optionally convert back to plain dict to avoid autovivification
```

A one-liner is also possible (since you've guaranteed the keys exist in all `dict`s), it's just a little ugly given how much meaning it shoves into a single line:

```
new_var = {k: [d[k] for d in var] for k in common_keys}
```

In this case, the one-liner is fine, it's just a little less flexible if you need to modify it; the explicit loop is easier to tweak, but more verbose.

---

Side-note: There is a simpler/faster way to compute the common keys:

```
common_keys = set(var[0]).intersection(*var[1:])
```

This converts the keys of the first `dict` to a `set`, then allows `set`'s `intersection` method to produce the intersection in a single call at the C layer (it's not meaningfully different in how it operates relative to your code, but it avoids a ton of interpreter overhead).

You could even make it silently handle an empty `var` by changing it to:

```
common_keys = set(*var[:1]).intersection(*var[1:])
```

which will produce an empty `set` for `common_keys` if `var` contains no `dict`s at all (which you choose depends on scenario; if having empty `var` is an error, loudly dying is better than silently doing invalid work).

Combining the two parts, would let you achieve the truly horrific solution as a complete all-in-one-liner:

```
{k: [d[k] for d in var] for k in set(var[0]).intersection(*var[1:])}

# Or to silently accept empty var:

{k: [d[k] for d in var] for k in set(*var[:1]).intersection(*var[1:])}
```

but that's truly horrific code, so I'd suggest splitting it up a bit.

Comment: This will not work if the `var` list has length less than 2

Comment: @MatteoZanoni: How so? And which part? Works just fine for me (on 3.11.4 if it matters) when `var = [{'a': 1}]`, producing `new_var = {'a': [1]}`.

Comment: My mistake, length = 1 will work but an empty list won't. `var[0]` will raise `IndexError`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni: Sure? But the special case of `0` needs special handling no matter what (your `set.intersection(*map(set, var))` will also fail in that case with `TypeError: unbound method set.intersection() needs an argument`, while the OP's code dies with `IndexError`). Personally, I'd tend to favor a separate step, `first, *rest = var`, followed by `set(first).intersection(*rest)` because I hate indexing and slicing with magic numbers; it will still fail (with a `ValueError`) for an empty `list`, but it hardly matters when the operation likely doesn't make sense for an empty `list`.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni The 0-length case is checked beforehand

Comment: @MatteoZanoni: Heh, you just made me think of a solution that would work just fine for an empty `list` as well. Editing it in now.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have the common keys you can use a dict comprehension and set the value as a nested list comprehension:

```py
{k: [v[k] for v in var] for k in set.intersection(*map(set, var))}
```

## Note:

To find the common keys you can transform the dicts into sets (this will make a set using only the keys) and then use set intersection: